# Best way to load google maps objects?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, json, google-maps

Hi I am using google maps on ASP.Net and sql server.
I call all objects' datas from sql server such as makers, polylines, polygones, circles, etc..
I guess I can load them via kml,georss,json or maybe just string. What is the best way the load them for fast and logical?

Google's documents usually have `google.maps.Polyline...` etc... I guess this is the one of way to call one type of object but I am not sure it is the right way.

Which way is more logical and better to use and how can I convert datas which come form datatbase to json,kml or georss.
And what is the best way the call it without postback in clientside?

Answer (score 0):

KML is valid XML which is natively supported by SQL Server with the `xml` datatype.  Storing your data as `xml` columns is probably the most straightforward way.

Comment: I am currently storing data as lat,lng,type,title etc... How Can I store it as kml I mean how many columns and which way I write and read it? In asp.net C# side how can I call it that maps know it?

Comment: Secondly I store some data which comes form some gps devices and it is really hard to store these data as kml I think. How Can I convert them ? Which is the best way?

Comment: It sounds like you might rather store the individual properties as separate columns with an appropriate datatype.  Things like lat and long would probably be best as `float` and things like title as `varchar`.

Comment: They are stored as you said, problem is How is itcalled from asp.net and show in map via kml?

Comment: You should be able to build a simple kml element from your queried data.  Do you have an example of the object you want to create and the source data?